# Use data mining in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, data-mining

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 on my computer and I want to use data mining with this version of SQL Server. My question is how can I do this? Because I've read some where that I can use data mining in SQL Server evaluation edition. I can use data mining in SQL Server 2008 R2?.

And I have one other problem when I want to use SQL Server 2008 Data Mining Add-Ins I can't connect to SQL Server and displays this error message.

> Unable to connect to server 'localhost'. Please make sure user '' has at least read permission to some database on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) which runs in Visual Studio.

You will need [Analysis Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175609%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) installed; if you don't have it just run the SQL Server installer again and look for the option to install it.

After that you can take a look at this post I wrote a few months ago:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic480010-147-1.aspx

I wrote it specifically targeting the Neural Network models, but it contains details on several background steps you will need to do.

Finally - since you're using an evaluation version, you may want to just go for SQL Server 2012 (that's what I use, so I know it works).